Why the mouse hover is not showing?
        // Create a tooltip
        const tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("position", "absolute")
            .style("background-color", "white")
            .style("border", "solid")
            .style("border-width", "1px")
            .style("border-radius", "5px")
            .style("padding", "10px")
            .style("opacity", 0)
            .style("font-size", "14px")
            .style("width", "auto")
            .style("max-width", "200px");

        if (data.length > 0) {
            svg.selectAll(".dot")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "dot")
                .attr("r", 3.5)
                .attr("cx", d => x(d["PM2.5 (μg/m3)"]))
                .attr("cy", d => y(d["PM10 (μg/m3)"]))
                .style("fill", d => colorScale(d["PM10 (μg/m3)"]))
                .style("pointer-events", "all")
                .on("mouseover", function(event, d) {
                    tooltip.html(`PM2.5: ${d["PM2.5 (μg/m3)"]}<br>PM10: ${d["PM10 (μg/m3)"]}`)
                        .style("left", (event.pageX + 5) + "px")
                        .style("top", (event.pageY - 28) + "px")
                        .style("opacity", 1);
                })
                .on("mouseout", function() {
                    tooltip.style("opacity",0);
                });


Above is the D3 code to make the mouse hover in the scatter plot. I want it to be like when my mouse moves to the dots, it will show the PM 2.5 and PM 10 value.
Why does it no display the mouse hover?

I believe your trouble is in the use of opacity to toggle the tooltip "on" and "off".  On a crowded scatter plot, the 0 opacity div will still be present on top of the plot and interfere with mouse events of the circles below it.   You should use display:block and display:none instead.
Here's it working:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<body>
  <!-- Load d3.js -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>

  <!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
  <div id="my_dataviz"></div>

  <script>
    const tooltip = d3
      .select('body')
      .append('div')
      .attr('class', 'tooltip')
      .style('position', 'absolute')
      .style('background-color', 'white')
      .style('border', 'solid')
      .style('border-width', '1px')
      .style('border-radius', '5px')
      .style('padding', '10px')
      .style('display', 'none')
      .style('font-size', '14px')
      .style('width', 'auto')
      .style('max-width', '200px');

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 },
      width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    var svg = d3
      .select('#my_dataviz')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    // Add X axis
    var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, width]);
    svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([height, 0]);
    svg.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    let data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      data.push({
        'PM2.5 (μg/m3)': Math.random() * 10,
        'PM10 (μg/m3)': Math.random() * 10
      });
    }

    // Add dots
    svg
      .selectAll('.dot')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'dot')
      .attr('r', 3.5)
      .attr('cx', (d) => x(d['PM2.5 (μg/m3)']))
      .attr('cy', (d) => y(d['PM10 (μg/m3)']))
      .style('fill', 'steelblue') //(d) => colorScale(d['PM10 (μg/m3)']))
      .style('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseover', function (event, d) {
        tooltip
          .html(`PM2.5: ${d['PM2.5 (μg/m3)']}<br>PM10: ${d['PM10 (μg/m3)']}`)
          .style('left', event.pageX + 5 + 'px')
          .style('top', event.pageY - 28 + 'px')
          .style('display', 'block');
      })
      .on('mouseout', function () {
        tooltip.style('display', 'none');
      });
  </script>
</body>



